# fetch call in react app doest not return body, same call works fine with postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a React app running in localhost and backend REST APIs running in localhost.
When I try to make a POST call to REST API, the call is successful. But the body in empty.

The sample code can be found below.

```
const body = await fetch("url", {
            method : 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(comp)
        }).then((res) => { 
            console.log(res);
        }).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Call is successful.
res looks like :
[returned object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTorf.png)

Same code works fine in Postman. Also all the GET API calls work fine from the same react app.

Comment: Didn't you mean to `return res.data` from the 1st `.then`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems

1. You don't return anything in the first `then()` and
2. You need to use `res.json()` promise to access the data.

try something like:

```
const req = await fetch("url", {
            method : 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(comp)
        });

const data = await req.json();

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hey @charlietfl, the one you mentioned worked for me. Thanks a lot.
However, as you had mentioned I can return from .then(). How does that work can you also send sample code for that?

Comment: `const data = await fetch(/* options*/).then(res => res.json())`